# Ubuntu dpkg error , after crash and filesystem error recovery

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, ext4, dpkg

Ubuntu recently crashed , causing it's partition damaged ( which is EXT4)
and Ubuntu was unable to boot , because it couldn't mount anything , only displays Busybox

So I used the Live CD to run fsck on the partition, which fixed it , but deleted some nodes
Now Ubuntu is working , but some files were missing ,
for example I lost the Panels configurations and Chromium's Extensions

The Most Annoying problem , that there is some files corrupted ,
for example when I try to install any program, I got this

> (Reading database ... 95%dpkg:
>   unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: 
>   files list file for package
>   'libservlet2.4-java' is missing final
>   newline

I tried these commands

```
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
```

and from GUI , Synaptic Package Manager > Fix Broken Packages

So this file "libservlet2.4-java"
Does anyone knows what it does ! and where it's location ? and how can I fix/get-correct-version-of it ?

Also , is there any way I could tell Ubuntu to Check for ALL it's files , and if there is something corrupted it should recover it form the CD ?

---

Edit 1
I just found the file @ /usr/share/doc/libservlet2.4-java
it contains the following files

> changelog.Debian.gz  copyright 
>   README.Debian  README.txt

is anything missing here ??

---

Edit 2
I even can't remove the package ! , I got the same error form dpkg
I even deleted the whole directory (/usr/share/doc/libservlet2.4-java)
but still have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like the binary cache of the package management system might be corrupted; you can try removing `/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin` to fix this (if this file doesn't exist, apt will re-create it automaticly).